# I'm trying to pause and play a video in webView but it is not working

Tags: java, android, webview

I've already used the below code but it is not working for me.

1. inside OnPause()

   ```
        mWebVideo.pauseTimers();
        mWebVideo.onPause();
   ```
2. inside OnResume()

   ```
        mWebVideo.resumeTimers();
        mWebVid`enter code here`eo.onResume();
   ```

Both are not working on WebView. below is the webview implementation.

```
         mWebVideo.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
         WebSettings webSettings = mWebVideo.getSettings();
         webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
         webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
         webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
         webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
         webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
         webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
         webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true);
         mWebVideo.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoId);
```

Comment: kindly edit here entire webview setup that you have wrote

Comment: @Muhammad, thank sir..

Comment: sir above code is not working  for me..please help.

Comment: @vijaymaddhesiya You're Welcome. Please add more code of your WebView class to get to know the problem.

Comment: @MuhammadFarhan ok sir...thanks to listened me.

Comment: @MuhammadFarhan sir, I'm trying to play  both video (youtube and mp4) url. video is loaded but video is autoplay in the background and also play when tab change.@thanks sir.

Comment: write `mWebVideo.loadurl("");` before `mWebVideo.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoId);`  and let me know.

Comment: @Radhey, thank sir but not work yet.

Comment: can you post your entire java file here?

Comment: @Radhey sir, i fixed the problem that was facing last 3 days..thanks for your helps..sir

Comment: good to know. if possible then post your solution as answer and except it. so this question is close and another developer can take reference of your solution.